# Set MaximumDate in DatePicker to CurrentCulture Property

Tags: c#, wpf, date, properties, datepicker

I have a TextBlock in which a date is getting shown which is set to CurrentCulture property. Now below that I have a DatePicker in which I have to disable all future dates so I have to set its maximum date to ProcessingDate. Please tell me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="ProcessingDate" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding ProcessingDate, StringFormat={}{0:d}, ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"
                               ToolTip="Processing Date"/>

   <my:DatePicker   Name="dpStartDte" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.CONTRACT.CONTRACTSTARTDTE, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" MaximumDate = 'WHAT TO WRITE' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of maximum Data, you could use  [`DisplayDateEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Which makes  any date that's outside of the specifided DateRange doesn't even appear.

**XAML:**

```
   <DatePicker DisplayDateStart="12/7/1941" DisplayDateEnd="8/14/1945" />
```

Add this style to your Resources and set the Culture,

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>  
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd MMM yyyy', 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: But how to generalize it? I will have to set DisplayDateEnd to the date set through CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Comment: CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
 dp.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
 dp.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = dp;

Comment: I am using your earlier approach. But it is throwing an exception. The vale in CONTRACTSTARTDTE is 9/19/2044 12:00:00 AM. This is line of code: dpStartDte.DisplayDateEnd = Controller.DataContext.CONTRACT.CONTRACTSTARTDTE;

Comment: what is the exception

Comment: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: I have used an alternate way to do this but thanks a lot for your help.